# how to optimize this code with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Тhis is code:

```
  if (urlGid) {
       $('.global_main').hide();
       $('#right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').show();
  } else {
       $('.global_main').show();
       $('#right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').hide();
  }
```

I think this is so trouble, how can change it elegantly?
can I code it without `if` `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `toggle()` for that. For example:

```
 $('.global_main').toggle(!urlGrid);
 $('#right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').toggle(urlGrid);
```

See docs here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if (urlGid) {
    $('.global_main').hide();
    $('#right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').show();
} else {
    $('.global_main').show();
    $('#right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just...

$('.global_main, #right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').toggle();

```js
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
$('.global_main, #right-tabs, #right-tabs-content').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="right-tabs">right-tabs</div>
<div class="global_main" style="display:none">global_main</div>
<div id="right-tabs-content">right-tabs-content</div>
<button id="toggle">toggle</div>
```